# Showing segmentation fault when giving grep inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My req is to check if a string is present in a file. I am writing script inside a .sh file INSIDE WINDOWS OS and execute the file by using teh command "sh test.sh" . Below is my test.sh file

```
grep "trigger" "D:\Jenkins\workspace\FirstProject\TestCI2\src\pack.txt"
```

it is showing segmentation fault. I tried findstr also like below

```
findstr trigger "D:\Jenkins\workspace\FirstProject\TestCI2\src\pak.txt"
```

It is showing FINDSTR : Cannot open D:\Jenkins\workspace\FirstProject\TestCI2\src\pak.txt

When i tried the above 2 codes directly in my cmd prompt it is working but when i put it in a .sh file and execute it the above errors are showing. What is the reason for this behaviour?

EDIT: Also when i give cat pak.txt in the test.sh file it is giving me segmentation fault but it is working when i give it directly in cmd prompt.

Comment: Is `grep` the command you are looking for?  `man grep` for details. Consider using `fgrep` if you only need to search for fixed strings and not full regular expressions. If this seems like the right approach, I'd be happy to convert this comment into an answer for you to accept. :-)

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: `findstr` is not a bash command. Technically, `grep` is not a bash command either, it's external to the shell. I gather from the pathname you're searching that this is running on a Windows box. If the tools you've installed generate segfaults, you should replace them with ones that work. And if you're actually looking for usage information on Windows tools (I'm pretty sure that `findstr` is a Windows tool), you should probably add an appropriate tag to your question. And if you're running something with `sh scriptname.sh`, you're either not running bash or you're in POSIX compatibility mode.

Comment: Inside the shell script  the file path should be `"D:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\FirstProject\\TestCI2\\src\\pack.txt"`. Note the double "\\".

Comment: @sameerkn i tried that still giving the same errors ie seg fault fr grep and cannot open for findstr. Like i said in my EDIT seg fault is showing for cat command also

Comment: Are you using CygWin?

Comment: @sameerkn I have installed cygwin and added it my system path. I am working on windows cmd prompt

Comment: Check the permission of file.

Comment: both my test.sh file and pak.txt file has rwx permision